# How make Popover from annotation on MKMapView scroll with map like Apple?

Tags: ios, ipad, dictionary, mkmapview, popover

If you touch an annotation on Apple's built in Maps app on the iPad you get a standard callout with a "reveal" callout accessory. When you press the accessory you get a nice Popover view with further details about the annotation marker.

All this is simple to emulate.

HOWEVER. Apple's Popover actually remains open and moves with the map as you scroll and zoom the map around. This is sweet. Sounds simple but I have tried many ways to emulate this and failed! Has anyone managed to emulate this?

[image: Screenshot of Apple Maps app]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the popover is being added to a view other than the UiScrollView's subview - which is the view that's actually being moved.

If you pass a reference to the subview in presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections, that should add the popover as a subview of the scrollview's subview, and allow it to move as the map (or whatever view is being scrolled) moves.  I'm not sure if the fact that it's a map rather than a vanilla UIScrollView will affect things, though.